# Как правильно: искренни или искренны?

Tags: грамотная-речь, окончания

"Они не искренни" или "Они не искренны"?

Answer (score 3):

В [**Словаре трудностей русского языка**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=vFimCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA154&lpg=PA154&dq=%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B&source=bl&ots=wlLktjzb12&sig=vpEjt0q0JToRiwBRmCOE9g3C8Gs&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLrbvpmuzZAhVhOpoKHZO1BZQ4FBDoAQhBMAY#v=onepage&q=%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B&f=false) говорится, что оба варианта одинаково грамотны:

**И́СКРЕННИЙ**, -яя, -ее; *кратк. ф*. искренен, искренна, искренне, **искренни** и искренно, **искренны**; *сравн. ст.* -ее.

Мне кажется, что такая орфография связана с тем, что есть устаревающее прилагательное [**искренный**](https://diffc_ru.academic.ru/2503/%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9).

*Чирикали птицы и были **искренни**.

Сияло солнце на лаке карет.

С точильного камня не сыпались искры,

А сыпались — гасли, в лучах сгорев.*
Б. Пастернак

*Там даме руку целовать при встрече можно

И это просто жест, не повод для интриг,

А чувства там все **искренны**, не ложны,

Там все бросаются на помощь, слыша крик.*
А. Шаргородский

*Во всяком случае, ради истинного бога, памятью вашего отца и всего, что для вас есть священного, умоляю вас, будьте **искренны** со мной, совершенно **искренны**, не позволяйте себе увлекаться*.
Из письма Л. Н. Толстого

Answer (score 2):

Орфографический словарь, Большой толковый словарь и словарь словесных ударений [допускают оба варианта](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&all=x):

> **искренний**; кр. ф. -енен, -енна, -енне и -енно, -**енни** и -**енны**